# Need checkbox to hide and unhide empty rows

Tags: excel

I have the following and I'm trying to just hide the lines that are empty and bring them back with a CHECKBOX so that I can add lines back when needed. I not want to delete them.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim DelRange As Range

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 1 To 250
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A" & i & ":" & "L" & i)) = 0 Then
            If DelRange Is Nothing Then
                Set DelRange = Rows(i)
            Else
                Set DelRange = Union(DelRange, Rows(i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.Delete shift:=xlUp
LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. On the "Developer" tab in the Ribbon, in the "Controls" section, click the "Insert" dropdown, then click the checkbox control in the "ActiveX Controls" section (not the one in the "Form Controls" section)
2. Click on your form where you want the checkbox to appear
3. Double-click the checkbox, and in the auto-generated `CheckBox1_Click` method (assuming this is the first checkbox on the form), place a call to your method: `Sample`
4. In your `Sample` method, perform the Replace below
5. On the "Developer" tab in the Ribbon, in the "Controls" section, click the "Design Mode" button to turn off Design Mode (otherwise you won't be able to check and uncheck your checkbox)

Replace this:

```
If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.Delete shift:=xlUp
```

With this, where "Sheet1" is the name of your Worksheet, and "CheckBox1" is the name of your checkbox:

```
If Not DelRange Is Nothing Then DelRange.Rows.Hidden = Sheets("Sheet1").CheckBox1.Value
```

Comment: thank you  MJH for the help however it still deleted it.  I want to have a CHECKBOX that will hide all empty rows when checked and UNHIDE the hidden rows when unchecked.

Comment: Not if you made the change I suggested, in which case they are hidden, not deleted. Look carefully at the row numbers on your sheet, and you will see missing numbers corresponding to the hidden rows.  If the rows were deleted, there would be no missing row numbers.

Comment: You are correct, I'm sorry it did not save. That did work but I'm still needing to make it hide and UNHIDE with a checkbox.

Comment: Your code does not seem to contain any logic for unhiding, so it's a bit unclear what you are looking for.  Do you need to know how to add the checkbox and make your code run when it is clicked?

Comment: Yes and I need it to UNHIDE when unchecked.  Please?  And thank you for all your help.

Comment: I updated my answer, hopefully that will get you where you need to be.